# Unable to pass parameter to web service from android

Tags: android, web-services, soap

My android code

```
public class MainActivity  extends Activity {

    TextView et,tv1;
    private static String url = "//10.0.2.2:8090/WebApplication8/du";
    private boolean add;
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "//db/";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "//db/du/helloRequest";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "hello";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item);  
        //  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1));  

        //    setListAdapter(adapter);

        //list1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list1);
        TextView tv;
        InputStream is = null;

        //String[] values = new String[] { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars",  
        //   "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};    

        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);

        // Create ArrayAdapter using the planet list.  
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        try
        {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 
            request.addProperty("parameters", 51);
            request.addProperty("username", "Rajapandian");
            request.addProperty("password", "Rajapandian");

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope =  new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 

            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url);
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
            tv.setHint("Received :" + resultsRequestSOAP.toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

here is my wsdl

```
<definitions targetNamespace="//db/" name="du"><types><xsd:schema><xsd:import namespace="http://db/" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8090/WebApplication8/du?xsd=1"/></xsd:schema></types><message name="hello"><part name="parameters" element="tns:hello"/></message><message name="helloResponse"><part name="parameters" element="tns:helloResponse"/></message><portType name="du"><operation name="hello"><input wsam:Action="//db/du/helloRequest" message="tns:hello"/><output wsam:Action="//db/du/helloResponse" message="tns:helloResponse"/></operation></portType><binding name="duPortBinding" type="tns:du"><soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/><operation name="hello"><soap:operation soapAction=""/><input><soap:body use="literal"/></input><output><soap:body use="literal"/></output></operation></binding><service name="du"><port name="duPort" binding="tns:duPortBinding"><soap:address location="http://localhost:8090/WebApplication8/du"/></port></service></definitions>
```

and here is my du.java

```
@WebService(serviceName = "du")
public class du {



/**
 * This is a sample web service operation
 */
  @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
 public String hello(@WebParam(name ="id",targetNamespace="http://db/" )int id,@WebParam(name ="username",targetNamespace="http://db/" ) String username,@WebParam(name ="password",targetNamespace="http://db/" )String password) {


 {


 String result="",user="",pass="";

    try
       {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users","root","789456");
   String query=  "Insert into users(id,password,username)                values('"+id+"','"+password+"','"+username+"')";
      PreparedStatement stm = con.prepareStatement(query); 

   stm.executeUpdate();







} 
      catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
  System.err.println ("Sql Exception"+e);
      }


      catch(SQLException e){
  System.err.println ("Sql Exception"+e);
      }

    return "hey"+ id+"\n"+username+"\n"+password;
}
}

    }
```

when i am testing this all works fine and data get inserted in mysql database but its problem from android data is not sent and null,null result is inserted in mysql table and null response is received on android screen 
in my server log i get this warning

```
WARNING: Received WS-I BP non-conformant Unquoted SoapAction HTTP header: ://db/du/helloRequest
```

kindly tell me whats wrong

Comment: Can you capture the SOAP request sent by Android and post it here?

Answer (score 0):

Your connection parameters are missing the `http` tag.

```
    private static String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8090/WebApplication8/du";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://db/";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://db/du/helloRequest";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "hello";
```

Note : **Soap Action = Namespace + Method Name.**

So, either your `METHOD_NAME` should be `"helloRequest"` or  `SOAP_ACTION`  should be `"http://db/du/hello"` (depending upon what you have used).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I cannot comment, just answer. The warning is not connected to the issue.

I was having the same Warning. The Warning is just asking you to "quote" the SOAP_ACTION. Let us do it:

Your code:

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://db/du/helloRequest";
```

The quoted code:

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "\"http://db/du/helloRequest\"";
```

Please note the \", which will send the quotation marks to the server.